# Rowlock and lock escalation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, rowlocking

I'm trying to use rowlock to prevent certain rows being updated while it's running but the problem is that I can't use the tables at all while running this:

```
set transaction isolation level repeatable read;
go

    begin try   
        begin transaction;

        insert into tableB with(rowlock)
            select * from tableA with(rowlock) where status = 1

        commit transaction;
    end try
    begin catch
        if xact_state() <> 0
        begin
            rollback transaction;
        end
    end catch;
```

I ran an insert for both tables while this transaction is running and they both waited for it to commit. What should I do to lock certain rows for read and delete but keep the tables usable?

For the record, the select results tens of thousands of records. The tables have clustered primary keys and status column has an index.

Comment: Have a read through this MSDN article on lock escalation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286.aspx. In particular: "The Database Engine does not escalate row or key-range locks to page locks, but escalates them directly to table lock" and the fact that there is a threshold at which lock escalation kicks in (~5000 locks)

Comment: Can't you hold off inserting into TableA while this is running?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend attempting to individually lock certain rows. I think you're going to run into more problems than you're trying to solve. The reason you're running into the locking problem you described is because of the number of rows being inserted, compared to the number of rows in your table. Locks escalate from row locks to page locks to table locks, at the discretion of SQL Server.

I think you will be much better off inserting rows in much smaller transaction batches to reduce the amount of locking going on. In other words, trying inserted 100 rows at a time, in a transaction, to see if you get the type of locking performance you find acceptable.

Comment: Have you any link discussing the "compared to the number of rows in your table" aspect? I thought it was a flat 5,000 limit regardless of table size as per Ada's link.

Comment: I've tried that. The magic number for me was around 500 per batch. 500 select->insert takes let's say 10 seconds but the table gets more than 500 records inserted per 10 seconds so I can never empty it :)